# XCode Linker Error when building library '.a' file

Tags: c++, ios, linker

I'm pretty new to Xcode and C++. I have a library that I am building and trying to link against. I have a project that compiles into a '.a' file which I then reference in my iOS test application. I continue to receive linker errors! I have the header file in my iOS test project. I believe I have all the required frameworks needed as well.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
```

"MyCompany::ClientSDK::AudioRecognitionClient::AudioRecognitionClient()", referenced from:
      MyCompany::ClientSDK::AudioRecognitionClient::CreateInstance() in libiOSRecognitionSessionNative.a(AudioRecognitionClient.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Build Settings for the library you are trying to link against.  In particular, look for the Architectures setting and make sure that it includes armv7.

Comment: Armv7 and arm7s are in included architectures

Comment: Ok, well have you defined the AudioRecognitionClient method (constructor) that the linker is complaining about?

Comment: Hi Jonathan! yes I did define the constructor. it seems to complain about any class that I attempt to instantiate. or any static methods. :(

Comment: The definition of that constructor and its usage in the question might be helpful.